# useEffect doesn't track changes when new item in my database is created

Tags: react-hooks, use-effect

I'm fetching all the user's transactions within useEffect() but when I create a new  transaction the useEffect doesn't reload then I need to refresh the page in order to see the changes. I've searched a lot and I've tried somethings such as useCallback() and useRef() with useEffect() but still doesn't work, probably because I'm not quite understand how to use them properly. When I pass the data that I want to be watched, in my case [transactions] I get an infinite loop because setState will mudate my state and then the component will reload hence useEffect will call my function and setState will be trigger and this will happen all over again.

```
const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getUserTransactions();
  }, []);

  const getUserTransactions = async () => {
    if (currentUser) {
      const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/transactions", {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: token,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setTransactions(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };
```

I was wondering if the async operation can cause this issue because in another project, I haven't had any problem.

```
const createTransaction = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (currentUser) {
      const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
      const data = {
        title: textRef.current.value,
        price: priceRef.current.value,
        category: categoryRef.current.value,
      };
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8080/transactions", data, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: token,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setTransactions(prevTransactions => [...prevTransactions, res.data.rows])
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));

      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

That because the dependency array of your `useEffect` is empty, meaning it happens only once, on the initial render of the page.

The purpose of `useEffect` is to react to state changes, it's unaware of your backend. So when adding a new transaction, you should change the state accordingly. I'd suggest something along those lines:

When you add a transaction, the server's response will include all the details you need to display it on your frontend, so when you get the response object, just change the state by appending it. Something like:

```
const addTransaction = async () => {
    const newTransactionData = (await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/transactions/add' /*or whatever your request looks like*/)).data
    setTransactions(prevTransactions => [...prevTransactions, newTransactionData])
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but I get the same result. I still need to refresh the page to see the changes. But thanks for trying

Comment: Another solution is to just call `getUserTransactions` every time you add a transaction.

Comment: It works as well, but is it ok to do that? I mean,  is it a good practice? At least I don't need to call my serve every second.

Comment: It's fine. Not ideal,  what I suggested on the first time is the best solution in my opinion and I strongly encourage you to debug it and figure out why it doesn't work. It might get slow if you have a lot of transactions, but you can always use paging for that.